# Unable to create XAP file in Visual studio professional 2017

Tags: windows-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova, xar

I have installed Visual studio 2017 professional.
Create new project in cordova app.

I need windows app(.xap). 
But it run on local machine properly. 
Build folder i m getting CordovaApp.Windows10.build.appxrecipe file only.
how will i get .xap file.

[VB_2015 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy3NK.png)
and 2017 version icouldntsee that option why [VB_2017_Community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzd9F.png)

can i install any more?

Answer (score 0):

try runnig your application in `windows-x64` or in `windows-x86`(if your running 32bit of windows) instead of `Windows Any-CPU`.and from the deployment target you choose either `local machine` or `simulator`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This app is running on my local machine.i want to check in windows mobile. So how to create  .xap file in the same project. please help me

Comment: You have 2 options.first you can plug-in a developer unlocked windows mobile and deploy the app or you can run it on windows mobile simulator.please make sure you have installed the simulator first.it could be either win 10 or win 8.1 mobile.either way in your projects bin folder you can find the compiled .xap file.

Comment: If i create app only any-CPU x64, x86 only.VB2015 Pro its shows windows universal platform , windows 8 and others also. Why here that option is not coming
Please check my screenshots.